# Wiring a RT314F12 latch relay to an Arduino

Tags: relay

I want to automate the lights in my house. To do this, I want to use a latching relay, so it will only use current when switching. I found a quite cheap latching relay RT314F12 but I do not know how to wire it up to an Arduino. Can any one please give a wiring example?

Comment: It's a two-coil relay. Treat it exactly two normal relays. The middle coil pin is the common between the two coils.

Comment: you send it "turn on" and "turn off" pluses on different pins. instead of setting one pin to a constant state. those pins should go through an opto isolator since you're working with mains. latchers are neat, i played with the idea a lot for the same purpose, but now i use mostly DC lighting with mosfets (i need dimming)...